# java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror couldn't find dso to load .so files. libgnustl_shared so is 32-bit instead of 64 bit

Tags: android, react-native, 32bit-64bit

```html
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName (SoLoader.java:703)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName (SoLoader.java:564)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary (SoLoader.java:500)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary (SoLoader.java:455)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.staticInit (ReactBridge.java:18)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeMap.<clinit> (NativeMap.java:19)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSCJavaScriptExecutorFactory.create (JSCJavaScriptExecutorFactory.java:21)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run (ReactInstanceManager.java:917)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
```

When I install my react native app it gives me this errors. How can I fix them? I think this problem begins from august 1 because of Google Play accepting only 64-bit version of the application  Touch senceste and you can see error photo

[image]